# Mulesoft: Expose web services/wsdl behind firewall

Tags: web-services, wsdl, mule, firewall

How to expose wsdl behind firewall?

Mule generated WSDL has endpoints to server where it runs but exposing it outside requires change of this endpoint.

Current workaround what we use is to use SOAPUI to export internal service wsdl, edit it in text editor substitute all internal addresses for external analogs, pack this wsdl and send it to the external consumer.

Is there better way to do so? Maybe some parameter to some component which generates the WSDL which defines the server name for endpoints?

**UPDATE based on comments:**

This is not general question about WSDL. This is Mulesoft related question. Mule generates WSDL automatically. Here is part what I'm interested in:

```
  <port binding="tns:Hello_Binding" name="Hello_Port">
     <soap:address>
        location="http://mule.server.internal.local/SayHello/" />
  </port>
```

It is generate because Mule server is at internal box mule.server.internal.local

But when this server is exposed externally it is "hosted" on external site service.mycompany.com, so WSDL should say

```
  <port binding="tns:Hello_Binding" name="Hello_Port">
     <soap:address>
        location="http://service.mycompany.com/SayHello/" />
  </port>
```

but Mule does not know about it and so WSDL is invalid.

Comment: Would you not just change the firewall? A WSDL is a PUBLIC document there is no need for it to be hidden and safe guarded.

Comment: This is corporate firewall. There is no way inside except through firewall. Externally we are exposed as https://service.mycompany.com but internal server with endpoints is mule.server.internal.local and this is what is shown in the WSDL.

Comment: Could you show me the WSDL parts which has you concerned? If it is namespaces the URL does not really have to exist. Also it is possible to using NAT and other techniques to get the WSDL exposed on firewall.